# Train multiple models with various measures and accumulate predictions

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

So I have been playing around with Azure ML lately, and I got one dataset where I have multiple values I want to predict. All of them uses different algorithms and when I try to train multiple models within one experiment; it says the “train model can only predict one value”, and there are not enough input ports on the train-model to take in multiple values even if I was to use the same algorithm for each measure. I tried launching the column selector and making rules, but I get the same error as mentioned. How do I predict multiple values and later put the predicted columns together for the web service output so I don’t have to have multiple API’s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would want to do is to train each model and save them as already trained models.
So create a new experiment, train your models and save them by right clicking on each model and they will show up in the left nav bar in the Studio. Now you are able to drag your models into the canvas and have them score predictions where you eventually make them end up in the same output as I have done in my example through the “Add columns” module. I made this example for Ronaldo (Real Madrid CF player) on how he will perform in match after training day. You can see my demo on http://ronaldoinform.azurewebsites.net

[image: Ronaldo InForm]

For more detailed explanation on how to save the models and train multiple values; you can check out Raymond Langaeian (MSFT) answer in the comment section on this link:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-convert-training-experiment-to-scoring-experiment/

Answer (score 0):

You have to train models for each variable that you going to predict. Then add all those predicted columns together and get as a single output for the web service.

The algorithms available in ML are only capable of predicting a single variable at a time based on the inputs it's getting.